# Drools dynamic salience

Tags: drools

```
global Integer rank1;
global Integer rank2;


rule "Data"
salience 10
when
      req : Requests(status == "ON")
then
   drools.getWorkingMemory().setGlobal("rank1", 8); 
   drools.getWorkingMemory().setGlobal("rank2", 6);
end

 rule "1" extends "Data"
 salience 8
  when
      req1 : Requests()
  then
      System.out.print("1");
 end

 rule "2" extends "Data"
 salience 6
  when
     req2 : Requests()
  then
     System.out.print("2");
 end
```

Here rank1 and rank2 are initialised as 0 in java code.
the output is 11112222.
i want the same output but instead of using static salience, i want it dynamic.

```
 rule "1" extends "Data"
  salience rank1
   .......
```

but the code output is 21212121.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the globals before you *insert* the facts. Globals are not evaluated dynamically.

If you really need a more dynamic salience you should create a class

```
class Salience {
    private int rank1;
    private int rank2;
    // ... 
}
```

and insert a fact with appropriate values and change them as required. You'll then need the pattern added to the root rule:

```
rule "Data"
when
    Salience( $rank1: rank1, $rank2: rank2 )
    Requests(...)
then
```

and you can use `$rank1` and `$rank2` in salience attributes.

Note: Almost certainly there is a solution to your problem that can be expressed in logic and without salience, the usage which is almost always a design flaw.